# Getting nested entity data resulting in stackoverflow error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have a many to many relation between 2 tables User and Joke. They are joined by a joining table fav_joke which holds the id values from these tables. Based on how I have set it up, it seems to work correctly when I I insert and delete from these tables.

Issue is when I try to query my User table to get all associated jokes. Again works fine but get a repetition of it in some inception form which ends up with a StackOverflow error. Refer to the image to see the response. As you can see, I get a User inside the Jokes which in turn has its own joke which has its own user and it goes on and on...

[image: Issue snapshot]

I am expecting only associated jokes under user when I make this query which in this case should be 2 and thats it. I think it has something to do with me having the @ManyToMany relation annotation inside the Joke Entity but I believe I need that. Please advice. Thanks.

Entities

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long memberId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "fav_joke",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "memberId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    )
    private Set<Joke> jokes;
}  

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "joke")
public class Joke {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private boolean isFav;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "jokes")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

Repositories

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User getUserByMemberId(long memberId);
}

@Repository
public interface JokeRepository extends JpaRepository<Joke, Long> {
    @Query("select j from Joke j where j.id =:id")
    Joke getJokeById(long id);
}
```

Controller - This call is the one throwing the stack over flow.

```
@GetMapping("/get/fav/member_id/{memberId}")
public Set<Joke> getAllFavJokes(@PathVariable long memberId){
    User user = userRepository.getUserByMemberId(memberId);
    return user.getJokes();
}
```

I don't think this is relevant. Just adding it in case. Doing this populates the fav_joke table which was created on the fly due to the ManyToMany mapping.

```
@GetMapping("/fav/joke_id/{id}/member_id/{memberId}/isFav/{isFav}")
    public String toggleFavJoke(@PathVariable long id, @PathVariable long memberId, @PathVariable boolean isFav){
        Joke joke = jokeRepository.getJokeById(id);
        User user = userRepository.findById(memberId).orElse(null);

        if(user != null && joke != null){
            if(user.getJokes() != null){
                if(isFav){
                    user.getJokes().remove(joke);
                }else {
                    user.getJokes().add(joke);
                }
            }else {
                if(!isFav){
                    user.setJokes(Stream.of(joke).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
                }
            }
            userRepository.save(user);
            return "Fav toggled successfully";
        }
        return "Unable to add fav. Invalid user or joke";
    }
```

Information inside the tables currently as follows: (joke table has 1k+ rows)

[image: Table Data]

**UPDATE**

Added the @@JsonIdentityInfoannotation as advised in the comments. The stack over flow issue is gone now but the way information is appending is incorrect.

This is the JSON format I am getting.

```
[{
    "id": 5,
    "question": "What is a gas station's favorite type of shoe?",
    "answer": "Pumps.",
    "users": [{
        "memberId": 1,
        "jokes": [5, {
            "id": 7,
            "question": "What kind of place should you never take a dog?",
            "answer": "To the Flea Market.",
            "users": [1],
            "fav": false
        }, {
            "id": 8,
            "question": "What do you call a cow in an earthquake?",
            "answer": "A milkshake!",
            "users": [1],
            "fav": false
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "question": "Why was 6 afraid of 7?",
            "answer": "Because 7 8 9!",
            "users": [1],
            "fav": false
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "question": "Why was Dracula put in jail?",
            "answer": "He tried to rob a blood bank.",
            "users": [1],
            "fav": false
        }]
    }],
    "fav": false
}, 7, 8, 6, 4]
```

Weirdly only the first joke stays on top and the rest keeps getting appended to the users list inside as potrayed above.

I was expecting the following (and planning to exclude the inner users data).

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "question": "J1 What is a gas station's favorite type of shoe?",
        "answer": "Pumps.",
        "users": [{
            "memberId": 1,
            "jokes": [5]
        }],
        "fav": false
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "question": "J2 What is a gas station's favorite type of shoe?",
        "answer": "Pumps.",
        "users": [{
            "memberId": 1,
            "jokes": [6]
        }],
        "fav": false
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "question": "J3 What is a gas station's favorite type of shoe?",
        "answer": "Pumps.",
        "users": [{
            "memberId": 1,
            "jokes": [7]
        }],
        "fav": false
    }
]
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `@JsonIdentityInfo`. Entities should normally be referenced (included by ID) instead of embedded in responses. (Your paths don't make much sense according to REST conventions, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @chrylis I will have a go with that annotation. I get it is off topic but can I know the issue with the paths?

Comment: First, it seems like "favorite jokes" probably belong to "members" as the first level of hierarchy, so it'd be more like `/members/{memberId}/...`. Next, "being a favorite" is either the presence or absence of a relationship, so I'd expect `/members/{memberId}/favorites`; POST a request with the joke ID `/members/{memberId}/favorites` to add one and `DELETE /members/{memberId}/favorites/{jokeId}` to remove it.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for tip. That annotation works. No stackoverflow errors and getting proper response. Concern is that when I debug, I can still see the nested result though.. Is that an issue and causing issues with my resources..

Comment: No. The debugger is simply correctly presenting you with the circular reference, which isn't a problem unless you keep clicking it forever.

Comment: @chrylis Ok. The Stackoverflow issue seems ok now but the json format is not what I was expecting. Still looks like the relation mapping is the overall cause.. I don't know or maybe this is a totally different issue. I've updated the question with the details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to break the cycles :

```
public class Joke {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("jokes")
    public Set<User> getUsers(){
        return this.users;
    }    
}
```

The same issue may probably happen if you get User , so you may also need to break the cycle from User:

```
public class User {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("users")
    public Set<Joke> getJokes(){
        return this.jokes;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Usually better to use `@JsonIdentityInfo` to map IDs.